# When running pages

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

My project in jdeveloper was run correctly no problem and my pages in project was show correctly ..but my PC was very slowly 
Now the page can't show in jdeveloper and word "loading complete" show instead of.
And when run any page that was running correctly in past .now show error 
500 internal server error 
java.lang.IllegalStateException
And my PC be faster
Another projects in jdeveloper show and run easy
http://b.up-00.com/2019/02/155133453906761.jpg
http://b.up-00.com/2019/02/155133454008312.jpg

https://docdro.id/izx2iFn

Comment: try clearing your jdeveloper cache

Comment: And simply increase the connection pool to your application module. By default it's too low